# Verifying How Tall a Stack of Pennies Is

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

The question is the following:

> Verify that a penny is 0.75 inch in diameter, and that seventeen of them make a stack that is one inch tall.

I know that a penny is 0.75 inches in diameter, but how can I know that 17 of them are going to make a stack that is a total of one inch? If there are any pictures that anyone can provide, then it will be very helpful. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I initially thought that the problem needed complicated math to be solved -- something that I realize now was not very smart to think about. This was a very straightforward question that I, myself, made complicated. Given the complexities of the problem in the math textbook that I use, I made the problem appear to me as a difficult question. I apologize for posting the question now knowing the very simple nature of it.

Comment: Can't get your hands on 17 pennies and a ruler?

Comment: What?  Just take 17 pennies and stack them up!  What on earth is the problem and why the heck did that not occur to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick search shows a US penny is $0.0598$ inches thick, so $17$ of them will be $1.0166$ inches thick.